# Wrong operator overload is used

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I've got a bit puzzled by the templated operator overloads. 
Say, I have a class

```
template <typename T1> base_matrix{
 ... 
};
```

Later, T1 will be either `double` or `complex<double>`. In the class definition, 
I overload the multiplication operator in two ways.

version #1

```
base_matrix<T1> operator*(base_matrix<T1>& ob) const{
...
}
```

This is supposed to be used when I multiply two matrices, e.g.  A * B

version #2

```
template <typename T2>
friend base_matrix<T1> operator*(const base_matrix<T1>& ob, T2 f){  
  base_matrix<T1> res(ob);   res *= (T1)f;     return res;
}

template <typename T2>
friend base_matrix<T1> operator*(T2 f, const base_matrix<T1>& ob){  
  base_matrix<T1> res(ob);   res *= (T1)f;     return res;
}
```

This is supposed to be used when I multiply a matrix object and a number (T2 = int, double, complex, etc.), e.g., A * 2,  3.0 * A

Now, when I try multiplying two matrices, the second overloaded version is invoked, which kinda makes sense sine T2 could be any data type, including `base_matrix<double>`, but this is not what I want (the version #1). Of course, this causes an error since the compiler tries converting the argument of this type to T1 (double).

For some reason, the first version of the operator overload is not invoked and I'm puzzled why.

I'm seeking for a conceptual understanding, so hope the minimal code I've provided will be suitable for this purpose. Please let me know what I may have missed or doing wrong.

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: Missing `const`.

Comment: @Yakk, could you please elaborate your answer a bit? not sure where const should go (these friend functions can't be const, and making T2 const  or const reference doesn't change the situation)

Comment: That is not an answer.  Just a comment; you are missing const on the first arg `ob`.